# WPF C# transparency / webbrowser

Tags: wpf

I've been doing some WPF in visual studio and I actually liked it.
However I stumbled in to some problems!

Currently I have this:
[image: Screenshot]
http://prntscr.com/jxeguk

As you can see I have a news-feed with a background in it already.
My question would be how would I fetch and store data in it, since the Web-browser does not allow transparency.

I'm just asking for ideas, as I could probably do it myself.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: We can help you: Can you add the XAML to the question?

Comment: Where will you fetch the data from? Is it a JSON?

Comment: @Tony i would like to fetch the data from a mysql database, but is this safe in WPF?

Comment: Yes it is safe, works well. I had a WPF app that connected to MySql worked fine.

Comment: @Tony thank you, that was all i'm after, however can i keep the header, text and maybe image backgrounds transparent?

Comment: Yes, for the News Feed you can use a `ItemsControl` with a `DataTemplate` . To connect to MySQL you can use `Dapper` and NuGet Package `MySql.Data`

Comment: Instead of a Web Browser control why not tap into the Web Services directly?  And if you absolutely need a webbrowser control you may want to look into ```WebClient``` and parse if however you want.